# Adding data to container class in sqlite Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, containers

I have a contailer class `ServiceMeasureCollection`:

> ```
> import java.util.ArrayList;
>
> public class ServiceMeasureCollection {
> public String service_id="";
> public String service_type="";
> public String service_measure="";
>
> public static ArrayList<ServiceMeasureCollection> data_arr=null;
> public ServiceMeasureCollection(String service_id,String service_type, String service_measure){
>
>         this.service_id=service_id;
>         this.service_type=service_type;
>         this.service_measure=service_measure;
>     }
> }
> ```

I want to call this class from an ArrayList and fill it qith sqlite data as follows:

> ```
> public ArrayList<ServiceMeasureCollection> getServiceProviderServices() {
>     ServiceMeasureCollection.data_arr = new ArrayList<ServiceMeasureCollection>();
>
>     Log.d("test", "testing if getServProv Services works " );
>     String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SERVICEPROVSERVICE;
>
>     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
>     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
>     Log.d(TAG, "testing if getServProv Services works " );
>     // Move to first row
>     cursor.moveToFirst();
>
>         if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
>             do {
>                 ServiceMeasureCollection.data_arr.add(new ServiceMeasureCollection(cursor.getString(0),
>               cursor.getString(8),cursor.getString(1)));
>
>             } while (cursor.moveToNext());
>         }
>
>     cursor.close();
>     db.close();
>     // return user
>     Log.d(TAG, "Fetching user from Sqlite: " +ServiceMeasureCollection.data_arr.toString());
>
>     return ServiceMeasureCollection.data_arr;
> }
> ```

Everytime I try to call it in my Main via `db.getServiceProviderServices()` I get a Null Pointer Exception. I am guessing this is because I initialize `data_arr=Null`. 
Does anybody know how to fix this or what the real issue is?

Stacktrace:

> ```
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                   Process: de.monobono.monobonoapp, PID: 4458
>                   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                       at de.monobono.monobonoapp.activity.ProviderServiceListFragment.onViewCreated(ProviderServiceListFragment.java:78)
>                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
>                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
>                       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
>                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
>                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
>                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5147)
>                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
>                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
>                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```

**EDIT:**

> ```
> public class ProviderServiceListFragment extends Fragment {
>
>  View myView;
> public String stampid;
> private ListView listView;
> private ListView listView2;
> private ListView listView3;
> public TextView dr_name;
> private ProgressDialog pDialog;
> private SQLiteHandler connection;
> private SQLiteHandler db;
> private ServiceMeasureAdapter list_adapter;
> private ListView lv_android;
>
> @Nullable
> @Override
> public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.service_measure_list_section, container,
> false);
>         return myView;
>
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     stampid = getArguments().getString("stampID");
>     super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
>
>     db.getServiceProviderServices();
>
> } }
> ```

Comment: If you have a `NullPointerException`, you also have a stacktrace. Please share it

Comment: @ 0xDEADC0DE Please see my edit

Comment: You have an error in this function: ProviderServiceListFragment.onViewCreated(ProviderServiceListFragment.java:78). Please share that function

Comment: I have edited my question. Basically calling `db.getServiceProviderServices()` gives me the Null Pointer

Comment: `db` is null on this line: `db.getServiceProviderServices();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your member variable `private SQLiteHandler db` is null by the time `onViewCreated` is called. This is causing your `NullPointerException`. You must add something like this is the `onCreateView` function of your Fragment

```
db = new SQLiteHandler(/*Required parameters*/);
```